# SQL Server & Disk Space

Tags: sql-server

I created a database on a local SQL server that we use for development. I created the log and data files on a second hard drive `(E:\MSSQL\DATA)`. I am using this database to do some speed tests so I created a lot of data (7 Million rows). I started running some pretty intensive queries and to get some test data I ran an update statement that updated all 7 million rows and now it has taken up all of the space on my `C:\`, which I don't understand since I put the data files on the `E:\`.

Is there some files on the `C:\` that would be growing based on me running queries on this other database, if so how do I stop it? I am doing with this database but I need to get my `C:\` back in order.

The database file group was PRIMARY, is this relevant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably the TEMPDB that is growing. Look here for some reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190768.aspx

You should really read the following article

[Capacity Planning for tempdb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345368.aspx)

Comment: How can I shrink this down? I skimmed the referenced article but didn't see anything that jumped out.

Comment: restarting the service will recreate it or you can shrink the individual files using the SSMS GUI.

Comment: Looking at my tempdb it appears to be 1GB currently :p

Comment: @Martin - What task/command would I do to shrink it in SSMS. Like I said I'm not a DBA.

Comment: locate `tempdb` in object explorer, right click then "Tasks -> Shrink"

Comment: @Dismissile... Just start and stop SQL Server Services.  This will reset the TempDB.   In addition you should read the article I posted above.

Comment: Doing that now thanks for your help. I restarted SQL and my disk space went from 4mb to 1gb. Will accept your answer in 6 mins when it allows me to ugh.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you may have a system database located on C: drive, most likely to be the tempdb database as the space consuming culprit.

Use the following query to validate where your data and log files currently reside:

```
SELECT DB_NAME([database_id])AS [Database Name], 
       [file_id], name, physical_name, type_desc, state_desc, size
FROM sys.master_files
```

Further reading:

- [How To Shrink The tempdb database](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307487)